# Save As, each filetype has different callback function

Tags: python, tkinter, save-as

I use python tkinter, and Import tkinter.filedialog to save as files. The program has functions to save each file type.

Using  `filedialog.asksaveasfilename` Returns file path only.

**The Problem**: how to get the file type, to call the right function?

Below is a sample Code of what I did.

> python

```
filename= filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title="Select file", filetypes=(("PNG", "*.png"), ("EPS", "*.eps"), ("TXT", "*.txt"),  ("XML", "*.xml")))
if filetype is TYPE_1:
    function_1()
elif filetype is TYPE_2:
    function_2()
```

Comment: "Using  filedialog.asksaveasfilename Returns file path only.". Why don't you get the extension from the returned file path and call the right function according to that?. Also, side-note: Don't use `is` to compare strings, it checks whether the two object instances are the same, it doesn't compare the two strings' contents.

Comment: Your idea works, but unless the user writes the extension himself at the end of filename, the filename will not contain any extinsion. Is there a way to get extensions attached automatically to filename? @GPhilo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the option `defaultextension='.'` to `filedialog.asksaveasfilename()` and then what ever extension the user selects within the Save Dialog window will be used as the "default extension" and that extension will be appended to the path of the saved file. You can then retrieve the extension with `os.path.splitext()` as shown below.

I also used a named tuple for the `filetypes=` option because I think it looks nicer but it is not necessary by any means.

```
import os
import tkinter as tk

from collections import namedtuple
from tkinter import filedialog


class MainApplication:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.b1 = tk.Button(parent, text='Save', command=self.save_dialog)
        self.b1.pack()

    def png(self):
        print('DO SOMETHING WHEN FILE EXT IS .PNG')

    def eps(self):
        print('DO SOMETHING WHEN FILE EXT IS .eps')

    def txt(self):
        print('DO SOMETHING WHEN FILE EXT IS .txt')

    def xml(self):
        print('DO SOMETHING WHEN FILE EXT IS .xml')

    def save_dialog(self):
        Types = namedtuple('Types', 'name ext')
        png = Types('PNG', '.png')
        eps = Types('EPS', '.eps')
        txt = Types('TXT', '.txt')
        xml = Types('XML', '.xml')
        path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title='Select file',
                                            defaultextension='.',
                                            filetypes=(png, eps, txt, xml)
                                            )
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
        if ext == png.ext:
            self.png()
        elif ext == eps.ext:
            self.eps()
        elif ext == txt.ext:
            self.txt()
        elif ext == xml.ext:
            self.xml()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I followed your example and it works just fine. Thanks!